# How to clip an Image when the canvas is zoomed

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

In the application I'm working on, I've implemented dragging images onto drop zones on a fabric `Canva`s where the drop zone is represented by a `Rect`.  When dropped, a new `Image` is added and I would like to clip the image by the rectangle that it was dropped onto.  I've based my implementation on this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PromInc/ZxYCP/

Because my page size can be large, I'm using the `Canvas` `setZoom` method to managing zooming in and out.  When the zoom of the canvas is other than 1, though, the clipping technique in the above fiddle does not work - example of the above with the canvas zoomed to 0.5:

http://jsfiddle.net/pagameba/jjLe9wps/

I have attempted a number of ways of adjusting the clip rectangle based on the zoom but I just can't figure out the right combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated the fiddle at  http://jsfiddle.net/pagameba/jjLe9wps/ with the fixed version.  The fix is to scale and translate the context based on the canvas' viewportTransform.

```
ctx.scale(1 / x[0], 1 / x[3]);
ctx.translate(x[4], x[5]);
```

and also to scale the clip rectangle position and size

```
ctx.rect(
x[0] * clipRect.left - this.oCoords.tl.x,
x[3] * clipRect.top - this.oCoords.tl.y,
x[0] * clipRect.width,
x[3] * clipRect.height);
```